# Regex to extract words in quotes out of a string?

Tags: java, regex

So, I'm looking to extract words (or phrases) within quotation marks (") out of a string.
For example suppose the main string is:
`The quick brown fox "jumped over" the "lazy" dog`
I'd like to be able to extract out and store in variables the words/phrases in quotes, i.e.
`jumped over`
`lazy`
should be stored in variables. The input strings will only double quotes when quoting (no single quotes).
I tried the following (rough) code for this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s\"(.*?)\"\\s");
Matcher m = p.matcher(<String>);
Variable.add(m.group(1));
```

It's throwing an IllegalStateException no matter what I input in. I have a feeling my regex is not working properly.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code lacks some `if( m.matches())` or `m.find()` which do the job...

This code:

```
String in = "The quick brown fox \"jumped over\" the \"lazy\" dog";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\"([^\"]*)\"" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( in );
while( m.find()) {
   System.err.println( m.group( 1 ));
}
```

outputs:

```
jumped over
lazy
```

Comment: That stops the exception from being thrown. But, the "lazy" part is still not being extracted out. I'm still using the regex `"\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*"`.

Comment: Cheers! Fixed it. I was following BlueBullet's index++ strategy. Whereas the capturing group is always 1, like in your code above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "The quick brown fox \"jumped over\" the \"lazy\" dog";
String lastStr = new String();

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\".*\"");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);

while (mat.find()) {

 lastStr = mat.group();

}

System.out.println(lastStr.replace("\"", ""));
```